# BULK COLLECT INTO multiple collections

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, database-cursor

I wonder if using `BULK COLLECT INTO` multiple collections guarantees that corresponding columns in row will have the same index in nested table.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tx AS
SELECT CAST(level AS INT) AS col1, level || 'a' AS col2, level || 'b' as col3
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 100000;
```

Data:

```
col1    col2   col3
1       1a     1b
2       2a     2b
3       3a     3b
4       4a     4b
5       5a     5b
...     ...    ...
```

And code:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur IS SELECT /*+parallel(4)*/col1, col2, col3 FROM tx;

   TYPE t1 IS TABLE of INT;
   TYPE t2 IS TABLE of VARCHAR2(20);

   vt1 t1;
   vt2 t2;
   vt3 t2;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO vt1, vt2, vt3 LIMIT 1000;

   LOOP
      FOR i IN 1..vt1.COUNT LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('i => '|| i || ' vt1 => ' || vt1(i) 
                              || ' vt2 => '|| vt2(i) || ' vt3 =>' || vt3(i));
      END LOOP;

      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
      FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO vt1, vt2, vt3 LIMIT 1000;    
   END LOOP;   
   CLOSE cur;
END;
```

Output:

```
i => 1 vt1 => 22418 vt2 => 22418a vt3 =>22418b
i => 2 vt1 => 22419 vt2 => 22419a vt3 =>22419b
i => 3 vt1 => 22420 vt2 => 22420a vt3 =>22420b
i => 4 vt1 => 22421 vt2 => 22421a vt3 =>22421b
i => 5 vt1 => 22422 vt2 => 22422a vt3 =>22422b
i => 6 vt1 => 22423 vt2 => 22423a vt3 =>22423b
```

So in every row there is always the same prefix. Or maybe in some circumstances it is possible to get something like:

```
i => 1 vt1=> 100 vt2=>200a vt3=>300b
```

---

Remarks: I am aware that I could define record type and use just one collection.

Looking for an answer drawing from  official sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PL/SQL Language Reference documentation from Oracle does not explicitly say that values from the same row will have the same index, but it does say:

> PL/SQL processes the BULK COLLECT clause similar to the way it processes a FETCH statement inside a LOOP statement.

Also, the chapter on `BULK COLLECT` gives examples that implicitly assume that values from the same row will have the same index.  E.g. this from example 12-22 in the *Oracle PL/SQL Language Reference* for version 12.1.

> ```
> FOR i IN names.FIRST .. names.LAST
> LOOP
>   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  Employee ' || names(i) || ': $' || sals(i));
> END LOOP;
> ```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-541A8B35-9B8F-432F-9E30-E73305A6E17C__BABCCJCB

Comment: Good example from doc.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, Oracle Support note 1066713.1 (if you have access) shows examples of equivalent blocks with and without `BULK COLLECT`.  You can see that the equivalent no-bulk-collect blocks use a single counter for all collections and _not_ one counter per collection.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have anything from official sources but I'd guess the desynchronization is not possible because that would imply that if you used a record type instead, you would have ended up with a corrupt record in your collection.

ex : `rec.vt1 => 100 rec.vt2 => 200a rec.vt3 => 300a`

It would basically mean that `BULK COLLECT` is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Matthew McPeak found, I think the key here is actually the [FETCH statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/fetch_statement.htm#i34221), which always select an entire row (or rows) from the table:

> The FETCH statement retrieves rows of data from the result set of a
>   multiple-row query—one row at a time, several rows at a time, or all
>   rows at once—and stores the data in variables, records, or
>   collections.

So after fetching the row(s), Oracle can place them into a record or one or more collections (like your example), but either way the index would be consistent (pull from same row).